# Simple MySQL query question

Tags: mysql

```
bins
----
id      min      max
1       1        20
2       21       40
3       41       60

pictures
--------
id
3
11
59
```

Basically, I want to select the highest picture Id and then select from the bin table the bin id it matches.  For example, for a pictures.id = 59 (highest), I want bins.id = 3.  Can anyone help me with such a query?  Something like

```
SELECT bins.id AS id
FROM bins
    JOIN pictures.id 
    ON bins.min < MAX(pictures.id)
        AND bins.max > MAX(pictures.id)
```

doesn't appear to work. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT id 
FROM bins
WHERE min < (Select Max(id) from Pictures) 
  AND max > (Select Max(id) from Pictures)
```

Hope it helps

Max

Comment: Does MySQL require the ANY keyword? Because the subqueries will only return one value, so ANY, ALL, SOME, or nothing should mean the same thing here, no?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
   Select id From Bins
   Where (Select Max(id) From pictures)
       Between Min and Max
```

Answer (score 0):

If the bin limits (bin.min and bin.max) increase with id as in the sample data, then the bin id for the 'max' picture id can be obtained using:

```
SELECT MAX( bins.id )
FROM   bins
JOIN   pictures
ON     bins.min <= pictures.id
AND    bins.max >= pictures.id
```

Note the use of `<=` and `=>` - otherwise the bin limit values will be effectively excluded (e.g.  picture.id=41 would not match a bin).

Can also be written:

```
SELECT MAX( bins.id )
FROM   bins
JOIN   pictures
ON     pictures.id BETWEEN bins.min AND bins.max
```

This **will break** if your bin limits are not sorted with bin id.